# How many degrees of freedom does a rank-1 matrix have?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Perhaps a stupid question, but I never formally learned exactly what "degrees of freedom" are.

Let $X = a b^T$ where $a \in \mathbf{R}^m$ and $b \in \mathbf{R}^n$. Am I correct in thinking that $X$ has $m+n$ degrees of freedom since it's specified by $m+n$ numbers?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a formal definition of the term "degrees of freedom" that applies in all contexts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r\leq n,r\leq m$ and $ E_r$ be the set of $m\times n$ matrices of rank $r$.

$\textbf{Proposition}$. $E_r$ is an algebraic set of dimension $mr+nr-r^2$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. Every $A\in E_r$ can be written $A=UV$ where $U\in M_{m,r},V\in M_{r,n}$ have rank $r$. (exercise)

Let $f:(U,V)\mapsto UV$ where $U,V$ are as above. Since $E_r$ is the image of $f$, the dimension of $E_r$ is $mr+nr-dim(\ker(Df_{U,V}))$ where $Df$ is the derivative of $f$. It remains to show that $dim(\ker(Df_{U,V}))=r^2$.

$Df_{U,V}:(H,K)\mapsto HV+UK$. Note that $U^+U=VV^+=I_r$ where $U^+,V^+$ are the Moore Penrose inverses (cf. wiki). Thus $UK=-HV$ implies $K=-U^+HV$ under the condition $UU^+HV=HV$. Then $K$ is fixed when we know $H$. Moreover $H$ is defined by $UU^+H=H$.

Note that $UU^+-I_m$ is similar to $diag(0_r,-I_{m-r})$.Thus the $r$ columns of $H$ are arbitrarily chosen in a vector space of dimension $r$. Finally $H$ varies in a space of dimension $r^2$ and we are done.